# Page can't be redirect when i upload image which that form in IE8

Tags: php

this is my function for add and edit data, In my form when i upload image i called validateProdImage() function for upload image, but this code is not working in IE8, this code is working fine in firefox and crome.

```
//for add and edit product
function addEditProduct(){
    $this->setGetVars();
    $this->setPostVars();

    if(!$this->submit || $this->submit != 1) return;

    // Validate image type and image size
    if($this->prod_image['name'])
        $this->validateProdImage();

    if($this->action == "add") {

        // Check if the Product already exist
        $q = "AND  prod_name = '".$this->prod_name."'";

        if($this->getCntProduct($q) > 0)  

            $this->setMessage("Product already exist!", "error");

        else {


            // Adding New Product
            $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_product SET
                    prod_id     = '',
                    prod_name   = '".addslashes($this->prod_name)."',
                    prod_code   = '".addslashes($this->prod_code)."',
                    prod_image  = '',
                    prod_weight = '".addslashes($this->prod_weight)."',
                    prod_type   = '".$this->prod_type."',
                    prod_desc   = '".addslashes($this->prod_desc)."',
                    prod_price  = '".$this->prod_price."',
                    prod_stock  = '".$this->prod_stock."',
                    prod_status = '".$this->prod_status."'";

            $this->connect->executeQuery($query, $this->connect->conn);
            $this->last_insert_id = $this->connect->insert_id;

            // Saving image
                if($this->prod_image['name'])
                    $this->prod_image_name = $this->saveProductImage();

                $query = "UPDATE tbl_product SET
                prod_image = '".$this->prod_image_name."' WHERE prod_id =".$this->last_insert_id;   

                $this->connect->executeQuery($query, $this->connect->conn); 

            $this->setMessage("Product has been addedd successfully!", "success");
            header("refresh:1; url=index.php?cnt=product&act=list&rs=1");
        }

    } else if($this->action == "edit") {

        $image = "";

        // For update image we check if new image availbale then we can call this function  
        if($this->prod_image['name']) {
            $this->prod_image_name = $this->saveProductImage();
            $image = "prod_image   = '".$this->prod_image_name."',";
        }

        // Edit Product details
        $query = "UPDATE tbl_product SET
                prod_name   = '".addslashes($this->prod_name)."',
                prod_code   = '".addslashes($this->prod_code)."',
                ".$image."
                prod_weight = '".addslashes($this->prod_weight)."',
                prod_type   = '".$this->prod_type."',
                prod_desc   = '".addslashes($this->prod_desc)."',
                prod_price  = '".$this->prod_price."',
                prod_stock  = '".$this->prod_stock."',
                prod_status = '".$this->prod_status."' WHERE prod_id = '".$this->prod_id."' LIMIT 1";
        $this->connect->executeQuery($query, $this->connect->conn);

        $this->setMessage("Product details has been edited successfully!", "success");
        header("refresh:1; url=index.php?cnt=product&act=list&rs=1");
    }
}

    // Save Product Image
function saveProductImage() {
    $imagename = "";

    $temppath = $this->prod_image['tmp_name'];
    $extention = explode("/",$this->prod_image['type']);
    if(isset($this->last_insert_id))        
        $imagename = $this->last_insert_id."_".time().".".$extention[1];
    else
        $imagename = $this->prod_id."_".time().".".$extention[1];

    $filepath = PRODUCT_UPLOAD_DIR.$imagename;

    if($this->prod_image_name)
        if(file_exists(PRODUCT_UPLOAD_DIR.$this->prod_image_name))
            unlink(PRODUCT_UPLOAD_DIR.$this->prod_image_name);

    move_uploaded_file($temppath,$filepath);

    return $imagename;
}
```

Comment: If the code's not working for IE8, then look at what the differences are in the POST data between IE8 and the other two browsers. Nothing in that code has `if (browser = ie8) { screw_up(); }`, so something's wrong with your form that IE8 trips over.

Comment: data insert and update proper but page is not redirect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
header("refresh:1; url=index.php?cnt=product&act=list&rs=1");
```

use

```
sleep(1);
header("Location: /index.php?cnt=product&act=list&rs=1");
```

Comment: @hardcoder also add a `die()` after the header. And what happens in IE8 exactly? Can you describe in a bit more detail?

Comment: `Location: url=...` is not valid. it'd have to be `Location: index.php?...`, and preferably a full-blown `http://yoursite.com/index.php...` type url.